# How to commit a mix of newly added files and modified files in tortoisesvn

Tags: tortoisesvn

A vendor gave me a tool to update my website, which added a lot of files and modified a lot of files.

I want to add all of the changes to TortoiseSVN, so I right clicked on the root folder of the website and clicked SVN commit.  Almost 4k files are selected, and 11k files total.

I chose select all and did a quick review to confirm that they were. I commit the files, and I see that they are all successes. Click OK.

I then right click on the root folder, and again do SVN commit.

Why do the same files appear in the list with modified next to them?

How can I add all the new files and commit everything all at once?

I'd post the version if I new where it was :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to do a SVN ADD before doing the commit to version them on the next commit. TSVN is just listing unversioned files again.